# Concatenating in a Jade Mixin

Tags: pug

I'm trying to format dates.  Javascript's `getMinutes()` function returns without any leading zeroes.  So to get the leading zero on minutes less than ten, I tried this mixin:

```
mixin formatTime(time)
  -var date = new Date(time);
  -var h = date.getHours();
  -var m = date.getMinutes();
  if m < 10
    m = '0' + m
  -var output = h + ':' + m;
  =output
```

This returns a strange string as shown here: [= '0' + m0:0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nIZ8.png)

Am I doing the concatenation correctly?

Answer (score 0):

here m is integer so it unable to concatenate just convert into string

```
mixin formatTime(time)
      -var date = new Date(time);
      -var h = date.getHours();
      -var m = date.getMinutes();
      if m < 10
        m = '0' + m.toString();
      -var output = h.toString() + ':' + m;
      =output
```